# Can Excel have some text above 1st page (and only 1st) of the table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, spreadsheet, headers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the Excel header on each print page to be the first row of the table](https://superuser.com/questions/287619/how-to-get-the-excel-header-on-each-print-page-to-be-the-first-row-of-the-table)

Can we print Excel report like this ?

```
-------------------
 Some description
 Some description

 Table header
 Table Values
 Table Values
 Table Values
------------------- 

-------------------
 Table header
 Table Values
 Table Values
 Table Values
 Table Values
 Table Values
 Table Values
------------------- 

-------------------
 Table header
 Table Values
 Table Values
 Table Values
 Table Values
 Table Values
 Table Values
-------------------
```

We can set printable rows like mentioned at [How to get the Excel header on each print page to be the first row of the table](https://superuser.com/questions/287619)
But this results in rather weird formatting: while the preamble itself is not repeated (printed), the rows are still reserved and stays blank, instead of being reused for the table itself.

```
-------------------
 Some description
 Some description

 Table header
 Table Values
 Table Values
 Table Values
------------------- 

-------------------



 Table header
 Table Values
 Table Values
 Table Values
------------------- 

-------------------



 Table header
 Table Values
 Table Values
 Table Values
-------------------
```

Moving preamble to the separate page (tab) is not a solution as well:

1. Report may contain several tabs with different tables and describing them preambles in each
2. Wasting the whole paper sheet for few descriptional lines it not much better than wasting blank lines atop of each sheet
3. The separate sheet with the description might be lost or get mistakenly attached to another table, etc.

Comment: Any reason you can't just put the preamble in the header?

Comment: Too long. Half-dozen rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems straightforward to me. Assuming this is your data:

```
-------------------
Some description line 1
Some description line 2
                       (blank row)
Table header
Table Values
Table Values
Table Values
(etc)
```

Set your print area as cells A1:B200 (or whatever), *including* the "some description" lines at the top. Then set row 4 (ie $4:$4) as the "Rows to repeat at top".

This works fine for me in Excel 2010.

Comment: Hmm... that actually works... looks like i over-minimized the example, for our COM-generated reports "feature" those blank lines.

I would have to re-think the difference, really.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you provide more detail please?

Comment: I'm sorry, i heavily misrepresented the situation.... it is more complex and the artifacts are less obtrusive.
Perhaps i'd let it go for a while or maybe would start another question later. Thanks for your help.